# Matrix trace based formulation of least-squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, trace

How can the following function be represented in a matrix form using matrix trace?

$||y-X\beta||^2 + \lambda \beta^T S \beta$

Note that $y, \beta$ are real vectors and $\lambda$ is a real scalar while $X$ is a rectangular matrix and $S$ is a square matrix with both matrices again having real entries.

Comment: And $S$ is a square  matrix I suppose?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make the trace appear, you can use the following formula:
$$
y^Tz=\mbox{Tr} (yz^T).
$$
Then
$$
\|y-X\beta\|^2+\lambda \beta^TS\beta=(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)+\lambda \beta^TS\beta
$$
$$
=\mbox{Tr}((y-X\beta)(y-X\beta)^T)+\lambda \mbox{Tr}(\beta \beta^TS^T)
$$
$$
=\mbox{Tr}((y-X\beta)(y-X\beta)^T+\lambda \beta \beta^TS^T))
$$